# Getting posts from subcollection in users collection with collectionGroup using firebase javasscript SDK v9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

What am I doing wrong here? posts state type returns undefined

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Getting posts subcollection from firestore:

```js
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(async () => {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
    query(collectionGroup(db, "posts"), orderBy("createdAt", "desc"))
  );
  setPosts(querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => doc.data()));
}, []);
```

Inserting posts data:

```js
<ScrollView>
  {posts.map((post, i) => (
    <Post post={post} key={i} />
  ))}
</ScrollView>;
```

Comment: Where have you defined posts? If it's `useState()` by chance then try setting it to `useState([])`

Comment: Thanks @Dharmaraj, just edited the code in the og post to reflect use of useState.  Good suggestion.  I did have it like that.

Answer (score 0):

You directly can't make the `useEffect` hook as a `async`. For that you need to create a `async` method and call that method in `useEffect hook`.

Here is the sample code, that may help you

```js
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
      query(collectionGroup(db, "posts"), orderBy("createdAt", "desc"))
    );
    setPosts(querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => doc.data()));
  };
  getData();
}, []);
...
```